# Yarn 2.0 zero installs production vs development deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, next.js, yarnpkg, cicd

So we are in the process of moving from yarn 1.x to yarn 2 (yarn 3.1.1) and I'm getting a little confused on how to configure yarn in my CI/CD config. As of right now our pipeline does the following to deploy to our kubernetes cluster:

On branch PR:

1. Obtain branch repo in gitlab runner
2. Lint
3. Run jest
4. Build with environment variables, dependencies, and devdependencies
5. Publish image to container registry with tag `test`

   a. If success, allow merge to main
6. Kubernetes watches for updates to test and deploys a test pod to cluster

On merge to main:

1. Obtain main repo in gitlab runner
2. Lint
3. Run jest
4. Build with environment variables and dependencies
5. Publish image to container registry with tag `latest`
6. Kubernetes watches for updates to latest and deploys a staging pod to cluster

(NOTE: For full-blown production releases we will be using the release feature to manually deploy releases to the production server)

The issue is that we are using yarn 2 with zero installs and in the past we have been able prevent the production environment from using any dev dependencies by running `yarn install --production`. In yarn 2 this command is deprecated.

Is there any ideal solution to prevent dev dependencies from being installed on production? I've seen some posts mention using workspaces but that seems to be more tailored towards mono-repos where there are more than one application.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? How your problem is related to Kubernetes?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak The problem is not really with Kubernetes, it's more with yarn. Our Kubernetes cluster uses helm charts and is deployed in the cloud with Azure. What I am trying to do is generate a production version of the web application to deploy to Kubernetes and with yarn 2.0 it doesn't seem possible. (Although I find that hard to believe)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and came to the same conclusion as you. I could not find an easy way to perform a production build on yarn 2. Yarn Workspaces comes closest but I did find the paragraph below in the documentation:

> Note that this command is only very moderately useful when using zero-installs, since the cache will contain all the packages anyway - meaning that the only difference between a full install and a focused install would just be a few extra lines in the .pnp.cjs file, at the cost of introducing an extra complexity.

From: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/focus#options-production

Does that mean that there essentially is no production install? It would be nice if that was officially addressed somewhere but this was the closest I could find.

Personally, I am using NextJS and upgraded my project to Yarn 2. The features of Yarn 2 seem to work (no node_modules folder) but I can still use `yarn build` from NextJS to create a production build with output in the `.next` folder.

Comment: Yea so sounds like we are in the same boat. We ultimately decided that having the extra packages there during production for our use case was a negligible impact. Like you said the `.next` folder is what will be served to the client so the dev dependencies will still be there but will never be used.